# On écrit « Ça sent le réchauffé », écrit-on plutôt « La série sent le réchauffé ou le réchauffée » au sens de « La série manque d’originalité »?

Tags: expressions, orthographe, accord

Ça sent le réchauffé.

La série sent le réchauffé ou le réchauffée.

Je pose la question car je suis tombé sur les deux formes avec ou sans accord -du masculin et du féminin- du terme « réchauffé » dans l’internet, me laissant dans l’incertitude, j’aurais la propension à croire que l’usage veuille que l’on ne fasse pas l’accord, mais bon s’agit-il d’une expression figée? quelle est la nature de « réchauffé » dans la phrase s’il en existe une, « adverbe », « adjectif », « nom », « participe passé » ou bien c’est un tout autre animal? Et qu’en est-il de sa fonction? Ça me laisse perplexe mais il faut dire que j’ai pris cinq verres de gin (verre sur verre) à l’instant où j’écris ces lignes. J’ai laissé ma raison au fond d’une bouteille de…gin. Trêve de plaisanterie.

Comment: En périodes de ginflation penser au ginger ale !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sentir le réchauffé* est une locution idiomatique donc tu n'as pas vraiment le choix du genre comme LPH l'a déjà répondu mais grammaticalement parlant, il n'est pas interdit de considérer qu'il s'agit d'une ellipse et donc de mettre *réchauffé* au féminin. Il faut alors aussi accorder l'article :

> *Ça sent **la** (série) réchauffé**e**.*

C'est cependant aussi improbable que *Ça sent la brûlée*.

Answer (score 1):

C'est un substantif.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9chauff%C3%A9/1)) **II** Subst. masc.
> **B.** − Au fig.
> **1.** Mode d'expression, œuvre reprenant des éléments anciens.
> ♦ L'histoire de ce Yankee (...) n'est qu'un réchauffé (Mérimée,Lettres à une inconnue, t. 2, 1865, p. 279).
> − **Réchauffé de + subst.** (indiquant de quoi est composé ce réchauffé ou quelle œuvre, quel aut. il reprend, imite).
> ♦ Tout ce système n'est autre chose qu'un réchauffé de subtilités scolastiques (Constant,Journaux, 1804, p. 81).

C'est aussi  un substantif massique.

- Ce film n'était que du réchauffé, alors elle a arrêté de le regarder.